# React is not defined, pero ya he instalado el modulo y ademas antes funcionaba

Tags: javascript

### Este es mi archivo principal:

```
import React from "./node_modules/react"
import ReactDOM from "./node_modules/react-dom"
import {Header} from "./components/Header"


alert(Header)

ReactDOM.render(<Header name="Elliot Williamson" description="I like amapolas and see fireflies"/>, document.getElementById("root"))
```

### Este es el archivo donde tengo el componente que quiero importar:

```
function Header(props){
   
    return (<header> <h1>Hello {props.name}</h1> <p>{props.description}</p> </header>);
}

export {Header}
```

En el alert la función (su cuerpo) se imprime, entonces no se porque no se renderiza el componente. Espero puedan ayudarme a saber por que.

**Funcionaba antes de colocar mi función en un archivo diferente.**

Este es mi archivo HTML, como bundler estoy usando [parcel](https://parceljs.org/) y le doy este archivo como entrada a todos mis modulos:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div id="root">

    </div>
    <script src="./App.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**No creo que haga falta, pero esta es mi estructura de carpetas:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**La funcion se esta imprimiendo**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Actualización

He podido dar con el error,  publique la respuesta porque puede servirle a alguien, sin embargo aun no se muy bien porque hay que importar react en cada archivo en el que deba usarlo, para mi que lo que ocurría con los imports usando parcel era que en un solo archivo se pegaba el contenido de los archivos que se estan importando, en el orden en el que importaba y por eso pensé que React ya existía cuando lo use en el archivo de mi componente, y por eso no lo puse...

De hecho probando ese bundler sin una librería, con proyectos pequeños eso hacia, en un archivo definía un objeto e importaba en orden. en los demás archivos usaba el objeto, porque ya estaba definido en el archivo de salida de forma global por así decirlo al código que estaba abajo de el usándolo.

Comment: tu aplicacion esta generada con `create-react-app` ?

Comment: No, estoy usando como bundler, una herramienta llamada parcel. https://parceljs.org/ , para hacer la instalacion segui este tutorial: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-up-a-react-app-with-parcel/ no descargue ningun proyecto con react instalado

Comment: El export del componente hazlo sin envolverlo entre llaves

Comment: puedes mostrar el html?

Answer (score 0):

He podido dar con el error, debía importar react en el archivo del componente que estaba exportando.

```
import React from "react"

function Header(props){
   
    return <h1>Hello World</h1>
}

export default Header
```